# GCP & Security Certification Guidance

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, virtual-machine, backup

First time poster here, I'll make this as brief as I can.

I am looking for guidance in what I should be certifying in with regards to the GCP platform.

I currently have my own company and we sell managed firewalls. I am looking into provide cloud based services for my clientele and wish to use GCP.

Basically I need to be able to set up Virtual Machines, Virtual Datacentres, Cloud / Hybrid backup solutions and of course fully understand and certify within the Security aspects of a cloud environment - ie: keeping my / clients data secured and compliant.

GCP help centre is a little confusing for me and I would appreciate any direction you could give me as to where I need to start.

Please treat me as a beginner with this even though I have prior experience with in-house cloud solutions at my previous employer.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start at the beginning and prepare for the Associate Cloud Engineer (ACE) certification. Google Cloud has a YouTube channel, several training companies offer courses on Google Cloud (Pluralsight, Cloud Academy, etc.), Qwiklabs offers hands-on training, etc. https://cloud.google.com/certification Even with other experience, plan on three to six months of preparation to pass the ACE, which is not an easy exam. Then prepare for the Cloud Architect. Once you have those certifications, you will know what to focus on next.

Answer (score 0):

Check GCP Partner program.
Being a partner you will be able to extend your clients or diversify your portfolio and you will get access to training
https://cloud.google.com/partners/become-a-partner